# Include a ColorField in a form django

Tags: django, colors, field

I'm trying to add a colorField using; https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1261/

I added these to my models.py,

```
class ColorField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 10
        super(ColorField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widget'] = ColorPickerWidget
        return super(ColorField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

Now in my forms.py, I am trying to use formField method, ( I 'am using a forms.Form form not a FormModel )
but doing:

```
star_color = ColorField.formfield(ColorField)
```

I keep getting errors: unbound method formfield() must be called with ColorField instance as first argument (got type instance instea) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is not really adapted for your use case, you just need a forms.CharField with a ColorPickerWidget, not a model ColorField as formfield

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    star_color = forms.CharField(widget=ColorPickerWidget)
```

Comment: does this mean It's a css problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using that syntax.

That code shows that there is no specific form field for ColorField; just a widget. You should use the widget directly:

```
star_color = forms.CharField(widget=ColorPickerWidget)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant but you could switch to a ModelForm instance and use the html type color:

`forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from .models import Website


class ColorPickerForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ColorPickerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields["primary_color"].widget = TextInput(
                attrs={"type": "color", "title": self.instance.primary_color}
            )
            self.fields["secondary_color"].widget = TextInput(
                attrs={"type": "color", "title": self.instance.secondary_color}
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "primary_color": TextInput(attrs={"type": "color"}),
            "secondary_color": TextInput(attrs={"type": "color"}),
        }
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Website(models.Model):
    ...
    primary_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#023458")
    secondary_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#ffffff")
```

The init function in the `forms.py` file is just for setting the title attribute to the chosen color value. Sometimes helpful when you want to see the hex code without clicking on the colorpicker.